# Android: In ViewPagerAdapter how to get getBaseContext()

Tags: android, toast

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), paramString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

I want to use the value from`getBaseContext()` value in the toast message.

Comment: Show more code from ViewPageAdapter class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably creating the adapter object from an activity or a fragment. If you are creating the Adapter object from an activity then do the following:

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getBaseContext());
```

if from fragment:

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getActivity().getBaseContext());
```

.

```
public class Adapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context mContext;

    public Adapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

}
```

Then in the Adapter class you can use the `mContext` to Toast or whatever.   :)

Comment: Thanks, but I trying to Toast in ViewPageAdapter.class,   in that instantiateItem method & calling setOnClickListener of checkbox

Comment: please explain more clearly what you want to do  :)   and post your mainactivity class so i will understand better

Comment: public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
 Context mcontext; 
    
 public ViewPagerAdapter(Context mcontext){
              this.mcontext = mcontext;
   }

   @Override
 public Object instantiateItem() {
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) act.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null);

  ((ViewPager) container).addView(layout, 0);
  return layout;
 }
 
 public void showToastMessage(String paramString){
   Toast.makeText(mcontext, paramString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}

Comment: thanks, done, your code work. doing some stupid mistake

Answer (score 0):

send parameter from activity to viewpageradapter ?

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{
       Context mcontext; 
    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context mcontext){
               this.mcontext = mcontext;
    }
...... Toast.makeText(mcontext,Paramstring,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

}